# Unable to convert a binary to decimal

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

My aim is to have a decimal which has same leading ones in binary as the user specifies, which is stored in the `unsigned long` variable `mask`; the remaining bits would be set to zero.

```
int mask; 
scanf("%d",&mask);
unsigned long subnetMask = 0;
int counter = 31,a;
for(int a = mask, a > 0; a--) {
     subnetMask += pow(2,counter);
     counter--;
}
printf("%ld",subnetMask);
```

Now, when the user types in 24, the binary string for the mask is 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000, and I am trying to convert that into base 10.

Instead of giving me the correct output of 4294967040 it gives me -128. I know there is a memory overflow in some parts, but I can't figure out where. I have tried several things, such as replacing `subnetMask`'s data type with `int` and  `long`.

Comment: %d is for signed integers.  try `printf("%lu",subnetMask);`

Comment: Note that you never use `mask` after reading in the value from input.

Comment: %lu fixed the problem. And, the loop condition changed and now it works. Thanks guy.

Comment: I would use the shift operator instead of calling pow.  Initialize subnetMask = 0xFFFFFFF; and then do `subnetMask = subnetMask >> 1` in the loop, and change your for loop to `while (subnetMask)`.  I worry that pow would be really slow.

Comment: do not use `pow(2, counter)`, use `1L << counter` instead

Comment: `pow(2,counter)` --> `(1ul << counter)`

Comment: Best practice is to enable all complier warnings and make your code compile warning free.  Is that really a comma in the for loop `(int a = mask, a > 0; a--)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the original problem without looping, on 32-bit or larger machines:

```
unsigned long subnetMask = mask ? - (1<<(32 - mask)) : 0;
```

Also, subnetMask doesn't have to be long on 32-bit machines.  The correctness of the expression is shown with this code:

```
 for(int mask = 0; mask < 33; mask++)
{
    unsigned subnetMask = mask ? - (1<<(32 - mask)) : 0;

    printf("%2d => %08x = %u (decimal)\n",  mask, subnetMask, subnetMask );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. The `%ld` format specifier expects a `signed int`. The number `0b11111111111111111111111100000000` definitely looks like a negative number when interpreted as a signed number in two's complement since the left part of the bit string is all 1s, so it doesn't sound too surprising that the input "4294967040" printed out as -128.  What you're looking for is the `%lu` format specifier.
2. `pow` returns a `double`, not an `int` or an `unsigned long`. You probably want to cast the `pow` result to an `int`, or better yet, just use `1UL << counter` to get the same result as an `unsigned long` automatically.